# Possibility of sharing variable from directives to services in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-services

I am in situation where have to pass LntLng variables to a service where an $http.get request is made using those latitude and longitude variables as URL parameters.

I tried some ways by using localstorage, this localstorage methodology was useful to some extent but it can set variables only once and not updating to new values if user change his location to some other place.I need to update the variable with new vaule every time user change there address.

```
.factory('someFactory', function($http) {
     return {
            get: function(result) {
                var latitude='value from directive variable';
                var longitude='value from directive variable';

                $http.get('http://www.someapi.com/?longitude=' + longitude + '&latitude='+ latitude + '&customer_number=00000')
                .success(function(result) {

                 });
            }
      }
 });
```

Directive:

```
popupPromise.then(function(el) {
     var searchInputElement = angular.element(el.element.find('input'));

     scope.selectPlace = function(place) {
          ngModel.$setViewValue(place);
          map.setCenter(place.geometry.location); // from here i will get new updated place object with variable i need..My problem is to access the 'place' object in service .

          ngModel.$render();
          console.log('rendering');
          el.element.css('display', 'none');
          $ionicBackdrop.release();
     };
 };
```

NOTE: I'm going to take value from directive only after the 'place' object is updated and will send that value to service after directive is fully loaded.

Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this easily via `$watch` or `$observe` (if place value is coming from the directive attributes) in the directive.

// Service

```
.factory('someFactory', function($http) {
    return {
        get: function(lat, lng) {
            return $http.get('http://www.someapi.com/?longitude=' + lng + '&latitude='+ lat + '&customer_number=00000');
        }
    }
});
```

// Directive

```
directives.directive('someDirective', ['someFactory', function(someFactory) {
    return {
        link: function($scope, element, attr) {
            function responseHandler() {
                // Your code on response from the API
                ngModel.$setViewValue(place);
                map.setCenter(place.geometry.location); // from here i will get new updated place object with variable i need..My problem is to access the 'place' object in service .

                ngModel.$render();
                console.log('rendering');
                el.element.css('display', 'none');
                $ionicBackdrop.release();
            }

            // Look for the change in place entered by user
            attr.$observe('place', function(newValue) {
                if (newValue) {
                    someFactory.get(newValue.lat, newValue.lng).then(responseHandler);
                }
            });

            //              OR                              //
            // Watch for any scope variable (if you have place object as stored in Scope)
            $scope.$watch('place', function(newValue) {
                if (newValue) {
                    someFactory.get(newValue.lat, newValue.lng).then(responseHandler);
                }
            });
        },
    };
}]);
```